# how to know if a specific value already exists in the database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When the user logs in with their google account, I need to create a database user in my firebase with their email, if a user already exists with the same email, I don't need to create another one. I wrote something like this:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                String userGoogleEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                databaseUser.orderByChild("userEmail").equalTo(userGoogleEmail);
                Toast.makeText(Activity_log_in.this, "already have", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                startActivity( new Intent(Activity_log_in.this, List.class));
            }
        }
    };
```

But I need to check a condition, before the query, and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider doing the following:

```
databaseUser.orderByChild("userEmail").equalTo(userGoogleEmail).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0){
        //Can create new user
    }else{
        //User already exists
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
}););
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Hello guy, first thank you for helping me, but I don't understand the condition you used.And get me some errors, like `Error:(66, 56) error: incomparable types: Iterable<DataSnapshot> and int` 
and
 `Error:(63, 79) error: cannot find symbol method addValueEventListener(<anonymous ValueEventListener>)` 
I tried your code after this: 
`mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {


                String userGoogleEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();` @ziya-erkoc

Comment: It should have been getChildrenCount() Sorry :)

Comment: Consider replacing `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` with `dataSnapshot.exists()`.